# Error only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays

I have this code:

```
for a in data_X:
    for i in a:
        if not i.isdigit():
            x=hash(i)
            data_X[column,row]=x
        row=row+1
    row=0
    column=column+1


desired_array = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in data_X]
```

and I the Data_X are these (only a part of the Array):

```
[['42' '-6725209669690155188' '159449' ... '40' '4017763880221344027'
  '-136014339944321305']
 ...
 ['30' '-6725209669690155188' '154950' ... '60' '4017763880221344027'
  '-136014339944321305']]
```

and I wanted to transform the numbers from char ( e.g '42') to int (42) and I thougt I could doing this: `desired_array = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in data_X]`
but I received the error "Error only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" and I don't know what can I do..

these is what I want to have: from :

```
[['42' '-6725209669690155188' '159449' ... '40' '4017763880221344027'
  '-136014339944321305']
 ...
 ['30' '-6725209669690155188' '154950' ... '60' '4017763880221344027'
  '-136014339944321305']]
```

to:

```
[[42 -6725209669690155188 159449 ... 40 4017763880221344027
  -136014339944321305]
 ...
 [30 -6725209669690155188 154950 ... 60 4017763880221344027
  -136014339944321305]]
```

Can somebody tell me where is the Problem?

thanks!

Comment: If `Data_X` is a 2D array, then `for numeric_string in data_X` gives you a 1D array, with at least 7 elements. You can't call `int` on that, for exactly the reason the error message says. Just naming the variable `numeric_string` doesn't change it into a string. And it's not clear what string you were expecting to get there.

Comment: Are you looking to get the _first_ string in each row and turn that into an int? Or are you looking to build a list of lists that converts _every_ string in every row? Or to flatten the array and build a list that converts every string in the flattened array? Or…? If you can [edit] your answer to show the expected output that goes with that input, it would help.

Comment: edited! I wanted only change the array from [ ['2' '3'] ['4' '5']] to [ [2 3] [4 5]]

Comment: @JulioCesar `['2' '3']` is compiled as `['23']` and you'll lose the space separated structure! You have to choose a different way/data structure to represent your data!

Comment: I get the feeling all the code you've posted should just be replaced with `data_X.astype(int)` (or really, it's likely that it should actually be fixed further up).

Comment: @Peyman the Matrix is printed so ['2' '3'] but what I want is [2 3]

Comment: @user2357112 I did these, and I have this error " Python int too large to convert to C long"

Comment: `data_X.astype('int64')`, then, if you're on Windows or 32-bit Python, or if that doesn't work, your integers are way too huge and you're going to have a really hard time working with them at all in NumPy.

Comment: @Peyman Most likely that's the output of printing numpy array. Unlike lists, numpy arrays have a str that's different from their repr, including leaving out the commas.

Comment: @user2357112 thats work, but I don't know is why I have now these Problem: "'>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'float'" when I do:

desired_array = data_X.astype('int64')
data_new=np.delete(desired_array,14,1)

what I have no is this array: [                  30 -6725209669690155188               154950 ...
                    60  4017763880221344027  -136014339944321305]

Comment: @JulioCesar That problem comes from some other line of code that isn't even included in your question, and it's almost certainly not related to this one. Create a new question, and include a [mcve] that demonstrates that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a list comprehension to create a new list, like this:

```
 desired_array = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in data_X]
```

Since `data_X` is a 2D array, each `numeric_string` is a 1D array, as long as however many columns you have (at least 7). (The fact that you called it `numeric_string` doesn't make it a string.) You can't call `int` on that, for exactly the reason that the error message shows.

If this isn't clear, you should try printing out the values:

```
for numeric_string in data_X:
    print(numeric_string)
```

… and it should be pretty clear that `numeric_string` is not a numeric string.

---

You *could* fix this with a nested loop. If you don't understand comprehensions that well, write it with explicit loop statements first:

```
desired_array = []
for row in data_X:
    desired_row = []
    for col in row:
        desired_row.append(int(col))
    desired_array.append(desired_row)
```

… and then you can turn it into a comprehension once you're sure you understand it:

```
desired_array = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in row] for row in data_X]
```

---

However, that still doesn't give you a 2D array of ints, it gives you a list of list of ints. It's *similar*, but it's bigger and slower, and you can't call numpy methods on it. (Althouuh you can still pass it to global numpy functions, at least.)

If you wanted to create a 2D array by looping, you could do that.

But as always with numpy, what you want to do, if at all possible, is used vectorized operations instead of loops. It'll be both a lot simpler and a lot faster, with no real downside.

What you probably want is [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
desired_array = data_X.astype(np.int64)
```

It's hard to get any simpler than that. And, unless you wanted an array of `dtype=object` holding Python `int` values (e.g., because some of your numbers are too big to fit in a native int64), it's exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks the problem is solved but I have now these Problem `"'>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'float'" ` 
when I do: 

`desired_array = data_X.astype('int64') data_new=np.delete(desired_array,14,1)`
 what I have no is this array:
` [         30 -6725209669690155188       154950 ... 60 4017763880221344027 -136014339944321305] `